# build.gradle error while importing project

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am importing a project into android studio but getting following errors

build.gradle is showing nothing in `build.gradle`. Here you can see my project structure too.

[image: build.gradle]

and giving this error

[image: this]

Comment: have you tried to invalidate cache?

Comment: yes for multiple times .. even I reinstall android studio as per someone's solution

Comment: firstly it was showing git.exe error .. which I solved, but this gradle error is still there

Comment: I noticed that build.gradle file is empty how can you build project without gradle file?

Comment: What version of Android Studio do you use? Have you opened project by pressing "Open an exisiting project" or "Import project" ? On the bottom of your screen I can see an error "NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle (...)" and it's already an issue on Google's Issue tracker -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140403764.
There is also a SO question about that.

But anyway, your build.gradle seems to be empty and that can be a reason of errors

Comment: Am I looking it wrong or build.gradle is really empty?

Comment: @Karzel What version of Android Studio do you use? I am using Android 3.5.  Have you opened project by pressing "Open an exisiting project" or "Import project" ? - Import Project

Answer (score 0):

check `setting.gradle` and find `include : 'app'`